# psycopg2 fails on aws glue on subpackage _psycopg

Tags: psycopg2, aws-glue

I am trying to get a Glue Spark job running with Python to talk to a Redshift cluster.

But I have trouble getting Psycopg2 to run ... anybody got this going? It complains about a sub-package _psycopg.

Help please! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWs glue has trouble with modules that arent pure python libraries. Try using pg8000 as an alternative

Comment: I started with pg8000 but its syntax errors are inadequate; I finally tried the (older) version of PyGreSQL that's installed with Glue and got around my problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

Now with Glue Version 2 you can pass in python libraries as parameters to Glue Jobs. I used pyscopg2-binary instead of pyscopg2 and it worked for me. Then in the code I did import psycopg2.

[--additional-python-modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDo9x.png)